# Hosted network not working windows 10

Tags: windows

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan show settings
```

### Wireless LAN settings

```
Show blocked networks in visible network list: No

Only use GP profiles on GP-configured networks: No

Hosted network mode allowed in WLAN service: Yes

Allow shared user credentials for network authentication: Yes

Block period: Not Configured.

Auto configuration logic is enabled on interface "Wi-Fi"
MAC randomization disabled on interface Wi-Fi
```

From what I've read, this should mean I can then start the hosted network:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=AdHoc key=password
The hosted network mode has been set to allow.
The SSID of the hosted network has been successfully changed.
The user key passphrase of the hosted network has been successfully changed.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan start hostednetwork
The hosted network couldn't be started.
The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.
```

I have tried updating my network adapter driver "Intel dual Band wireless-AC 765", however it didn't fix it. From reading some of the other questions on this site, I noticed I don't have a driver called "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter", could this be causing the issue? I'm not very competent at IT, so if I haven't explained myself clearly, just let me know so I can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might encounter the same problem. This link helped me. [Can't Start Hosted Network.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182084/cant-start-hostednetwork)

The following text is copied from the answer in the above link :

> This happen after you disable via Control Panel -> network adapters ->
>   right click button on the virtual connection -> disable
>
> To fix that go to Device Manager (Windows-key + x + m on windows 8),
>   then open the network adapters tree , right click button on Microsoft
>   Hosted Network Virtual Adapter and click on enable.
>
> Try now with the command netsh wlan start hostednetwork with admin
>   privileges. It should work.
>
> Note: If you don't see the network adapter with name 'Microsoft Hosted
>   Network Virtual Adapter' try on menu -> view -> show hidden devices in
>   the Device Manager window.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with that network card and I fixed it by installing the app Wifi Direct Access Point from the Microsoft Store. It looks like is a driver issue, HostedNetwork is not well supported by Windows 10 on some hardware.