# Keeping windows 10 laptop hotspot on

Tags: windows

I am having a problem of which when no one connects to my hotspot, the system will turn off the hotspot.

I wish to get it on all the time, but I do not even know a way to approach the setting. My version of windows is Windows 10 version 1703

Is this action possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try it via command propmt: `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`, I've read somewhere that this would keep that on.

Comment: not working to me, it says there 'The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.'

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18388575/8051589

Comment: didnt work as well even though i have enabled to view hidden, but the device is not there

Comment: What's about the second answer on that SO question I posted?

Comment: not working, i have set the mode to allow, set the SSID and the key, but the result is the same,

Comment: apparently using the netsh wlan start hostednetwork is not possible because mine is not supported, i have checked this using netsh wlan show driver | findstr Hosted

Comment: Seraphinite Wi-Fi Hotspot 
https://www.s-sols.com/products/windows/wi-fi-hotspot